# How can I configure apache to respond 400 when request contains an invalid byte sequence?

Tags: url, apache-2.2, phusion-passenger

On web application someone is making invalid HTTP request containing invalid bytes.

According to [RFC 3986, section 2](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#sec-2) only ASCII characters are allowed in the HTTP Request line. However I am receiving request contains the byte sequence (in Hex) \0xC3 \0xA6, which is the UTF-8 byte sequence for '`æ`' (which of course should have been percent encoded as `%C3%A6`). In the apache log they show up as `\xc3\xa6`. Nevertheless this is an invalid HTTP request, so I would like configure apache to respond with an error 400 Bad Request in this case instead of delegating the request to my Rails app. How can I do that?

BTW: My web application is a Ruby on Rails (served by Phusion Passenger mod_rails 3.0.13), but I don't think it is relevant to the question, as I am interested in configuring apache so that these requests never reaches my application.

Comment: Remember to figure out who's sending these invalid requests and file a bug report with them.

Comment: It can be quite difficult to figure out who is sending those requests when all you have is an IP address. I guess the senders are some sort of hackers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded configuring apache using mod_rewrite to respond 400 Bad request containing URLs with invalid characters.

Inspired from [this tutorial](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/preventing-requests-with-invalid-characters/) I added this snippet to my apache configuration file:

```
# unreserved [a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\_\~]
# reserved gen-delims [\:\/\?\#\[\]\@]
# reserved sub-delims [\!\$\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\;\=]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,9}\ [a-zA-Z0-9\%\-\.\_\~\:\/\?\#\[\]\@\!\$\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\;\=]+(\ .+)?$
RewriteRule ^.*$  -  [redirect=400,last]
```

See [RFC3986, section 2.2 and 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) for details on the valid characters.